# Cocoa Binding NSCollectionView Always Select the Last Object

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nscollectionview

I m binding the `NSCollectionView` and `NSArrayController` with a bunch of models, the `NSCollectionViewItems` are displayed just fine. I have bound the controller key "`selectionIndexes`" for the `NSCollectionView`, but when I manually select one of the NSCollectionItem I always got the last `representedObject` for the `NSCollectionItem`
This my NSCollectionView bindings:
[image: NSCollectionView Bindings]

I can not get the right representedObject from my NSCollectionView DataSource, please help me, thank you!
(NSCollectionView is single selection & does not allow empty selection.)

Comment: Where and how do you get the representedObject for the NSCollectionItem? Do you use bindings or a datasource?

Comment: @Willeke In the `NSCollectionView` delegate method: `- (void)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSSet<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths` and I called `[_arrayController selectedObjects]`, I m using bindings.

Comment: The modern `NSCollectionView` which uses layouts and index paths instead of indexes doesn't work very well with bindings. Use a datasource.